# Fiddler Autoresponder when = in URL

Tags: fiddler

I'm trying to make an auto response for a website, let me take an exemple

Website : http://mywebsite.com/1.0/?appID=blah_blah&appVersion=RandomNumber&getAppicationSettings=blah_blah

I'd like that Fiddler match the autoresponse after, for exemple, `"appVersion="` I've tried to put `"REGEX:http://mywebsite.com/1.0/?appID=blah_blah&appVersion=.*"` but it doesn't work.

I don't know if you know what I mean, I have trouble to explain it. :(

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be to just change the rule to

`http://mywebsite.com/1.0/?appID=blah_blah&appVersion=`

If you need to use a regular expression, the expression needs to be valid, with escaping of characters that have a meaning in regular expressions. E.g. more like:

`REGEX:mywebsite\.com\/1\.0\/\?appID=blah_blah&appVersion=[\d]+&getAppicationSettings=blah_blah`